# Scala Option(null) expected as None but I got Some(0)

Tags: scala, option-type, scala-java-interop

```scala
val i: java.lang.Integer = null
val o: Option[Int] = Option(i) // This yields Some(0)
```

What is the safe way to convert `null: java.lang.Integer` to Scala `Option[Int]`?

Answer (score 21):

You are mixing `Int` and `java.lang.Integer` so

```
val i: java.lang.Integer = null
val o: Option[Int] = Option(i)
```

implicitly converts to

```
val o: Option[Int] = Option(Integer2int(i))
```

which becomes

```
val o: Option[Int] = Option(null.asInstanceOf[Int])
```

thus

```
val o: Option[Int] = Some(0)
```

If you want to work with `java.lang.Integer`, then write

```
val o: Option[java.lang.Integer] = Option(i)
// o: Option[Integer] = None
```

Comment: This was recently asked somewhere, so it's a real gotcha. Maybe the problem is relying on inference: `Option[Integer](i).map(_.intValue)` seems most idiomatic to me, since it says what it is doing. Also, use `-Xlint` to see the warning for the `val o`!

Comment: To avoid a boxing roundtrip, ` val x: Option[Int] = Option(i).asInstanceOf[Option[Int]]` where `Integer` is inferred.

Comment: more like `forced to` :)

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be happening because you are creating the `Option`, and converting it to an `Int` in one step (@MarioGalic's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60600735/31506) explains why this is happening).

This does what you want:

```
scala> val o: java.lang.Integer = null
o: Integer = null

scala> val i: Option[Int] = Option(o).map(_.toInt)
i: Option[Int] = None

scala> val o1: java.lang.Integer = 1
o1: Integer = 1

scala> val i1: Option[Int] = Option(o1).map(_.toInt)
i1: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Comment: On the other answer, I suggested `_.intValue`. I guess it only saves the conversion call.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue before. 
This questionable behavior is known by the Scala team.
Seems that changing it breaks something elsewhere.
See https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11236 and https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5176 .

Comment: The really questionable behaviour is treating `null` as an integer. This is presumably a hangover from `C` where it is OK to assign `0` to a pointer. But this doesn't mean that the resulting pointer is `0`, so it is dodgy to switch between the two even in `C`.

Comment: `Integer` most probably came from Java code so 'don't treat null as an integer' is not an actionable advice. And we explicitly check this Integer for nullability using `Option.apply`. So we get unexpected output w/o explicitly doing any unsafe operations.

Comment: The point is that you can't blame Scala for "questionable behaviour" when the root cause is Java. The actionable advice is to have explicit conversion from Java types to the equivalent Scala types rather than use implicit conversion. (Hence `JavaConverters` rather than `JavaConversion`)

Comment: Well, I can and I do blame Scala for not emitting compilation error/warning in this case. Even runtime crash would be better. Even in my company alone 2 developers with 5+ years of experience in Scala have hit this problem.

Comment: A runtime crash would require a check for `null` every time a `java.lang.Integer` is converted to `Int`, which seems excessive. Don't forget that the issue here is the type declaration on the result, not `Option(<Integer>)` itself.

Comment: @Tim It would be very easy to get a runtime crash, by simply calling `theInteger.intValue()`. Avoiding that crash is what costs an extra runtime check. In older versions of Scala, this conversion indeed produced an NPE; it was reported as a bug, and fixed to the current behavior. I'm not a Scala expert, but I dug up [scala-dev#355](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/355) and [scala#5176](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5176) as historical context.